# MySQL Error 2014 - Commands out of sync - when trying to call consecutive stored procs

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin, nested-sets

I have a hierarchical MySQL table setup using the Nested Set model.  I have created a stored proc which allows me to delete an organization.

When I try making consecutive calls to the stored proc, I get the following error referring to the second CALL command:

> 2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Here is the SQL I am running:

```
SELECT @id := id, 
       @parent_id := parent_id 
  FROM organization 
 WHERE name = 'TESTDEAL';

CALL deleteOrg(@id);
CALL deleteOrg(@parent_id);
```

And here is my Stored Procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE deleteOrg(IN IN_ID INT)

MODIFIES SQL DATA

BEGIN 

    START TRANSACTION;

    SELECT @org_id := id, 
           @myLeft := lft, 
           @myRight := rgt,  
           @myWidth := rgt - lft + 1 
      FROM organization 
     WHERE id = IN_ID;

    # delete statements for removing roles and other dependencies

    DELETE FROM organization 
     WHERE id = @org_id;

    UPDATE organization 
       SET rgt = rgt - @myWidth 
     WHERE rgt > @myRight;

    UPDATE organization 
       SET lft = lft - @myWidth 
     WHERE lft > @myRight;

    COMMIT;

END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Why would the second command be failing?  Is MySQL trying to execute the second CALL command before the first one has been committed?  Is there a way I can force the first one to fully execute before calling the second?

EDIT: organization table is using InnoDB

EDIT: Tried removing START TRANSACTION; and COMMIT; but am still getting same error

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this might have something to do with the way you are assigning your variables.

My advice is to declare local variables inside your procedure, and to assign them using `SELECT...INTO`. This is a good practice in general, and may help you with your problem.

Here's what your procedure would look like:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS deleteOrg $$

CREATE PROCEDURE deleteOrg(IN IN_ID INT)

MODIFIES SQL DATA

BEGIN 
  DECLARE V_ORG_ID INT;
  DECLARE V_MY_LEFT INT;
  DECLARE V_MY_RIGHT INT;
  DECLARE V_MY_WIDTH INT;

    START TRANSACTION;

    SELECT id, 
           lft, 
           rgt, 
           rgt - lft + 1
      into V_ORG_ID, 
           V_MY_LEFT, 
           V_MY_RIGHT,  
           V_MY_WIDTH
      FROM organization 
     WHERE id = IN_ID;

    -- delete statements for removing roles and other dependencies

    DELETE FROM organization 
     WHERE id = V_ORG_ID;

    UPDATE organization 
       SET rgt = rgt - V_MY_WIDTH 
     WHERE rgt > V_MY_RIGHT;

    UPDATE organization 
       SET lft = lft - V_MY_WIDTH 
     WHERE lft > V_MY_LEFT;

COMMIT;

END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error only seems to be occurring when importing an SQL script from phpMyAdmin.  Importing the script from the command line or using the command line does not result in an error.  I'm assuming this error has to do with phpMyAdmin and not MySQL.  (I have also seen other strange behaviour from phpMyAdmin relating to Stored Procedures - I am using phpMyAdmin v3.3.2)

Answer (score -1):

I'm looking for the answer too, AFAIK it's related to the recordset returned by the first SP. You must 'read' the recordset to empty it and then make a new CALL.