# MySQL "commands out of sync" in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

I have just come across the MySQL [Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commands-out-of-sync.html) error. It's come up on SO before, but those questions and answers refer to application-level code.

Here is a file I'm trying to import through phpmyadmin. (It is simplified from the real code.) **I am confused because I have other groups of drop/create/call statements in other files which imported fine.**

What is causing the error?

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `c9gtd`.`select_changes`;

CREATE PROCEDURE `c9gtd`.`select_changes`
(
    IN `user_id` INT,
    IN `days`    INT
)
SELECT
    0 AS `id`
;

CALL `c9gtd`.`select_changes`(-1,-1); -- Test



DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `c9gtd`.`select_info`;

CREATE PROCEDURE `c9gtd`.`select_info` (IN `id` INT) -- ERROR IS HERE
    SELECT
    0 AS `id`
;

CALL `c9gtd`.`select_info`(-1); -- Test
```

Comment: Do other groups use the same form of `SELECT` without `INTO`?

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072488/mysql-error-2014-commands-out-of-sync-when-trying-to-call-consecutive-stored?rq=1 because the code works for me in MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 0):

This is because both stored procedures are SELECTs. All the stored procedures up to this point have been UPDATEs: having multiple CALLs in one connection is ok when no data is returned.